# jQuery display object properties

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'd like to display the content of a JSON arriving from a servlet into the browser inside a simple table made of two columns: key and value.
In pure HTML I'd use the definition list  tag but I have to load everything dynamically and I don't want to read the JSON, parse it and create hand by hand the html code.
Another way to do it is having a table with the first headers column filled by the property keys and the second data column filled by the properties values.

But I'd like to keep the code clean so I was wondering if there is some widget or similar to do it in another way.

The best should be a way to use the datatables plugin.

P.S. I try to make an example.
Starting from this

```
{
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "c": 6
}
```

I want to reach this

```
a A
b B
c 6
```

Maybe printing it inside a table and showing differently the first column, that is in fact an header.

Comment: If you're not going to parse the JSON and create the markup, how on earth are you going to do it, I'm dying to know, as it would make all our lifes so much easier to type "print" and the string appears formatted in a table just the way we want ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var a = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "c": 6
}
$.each(a,function(k,v){
    alert("key:"+k+" value:"+v);
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/znSjC/)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear when I wrote I don't want to cycle over the object read from the json and write the html tags from the javascript. I'd like to use a jqueryui widget.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `for...in` loop. It will iterate over the property names of the object, and then you can use the name and bracket notation to get the value.

```
var obj = {
    "a":"A",
    "b":"B",
    "c":6
}

for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop+" "+obj[prop]);
}
```

For HTML output, just change the body of the `for...in` loop to something like `document.write("<tr><td>"+prop+"</td><td>"+obj[prop]+"</td></tr>")` (or edit innerHTML on an element)

Comment: I wrote that I do not want to do it manually. I'd like to use a widget like the datatables one.

Comment: A jquery ui widget is just going to cycle over the JSON anyway...and honestly getting a whole separate bit of code (and jQuery) is unnecessary for your task. If you are hell bent on using a plugin, try http://plugins.jquery.com/ (though to get the output you want, you will most likely have to modify it which is another can of worms).

Comment: But I use jQuery for many other things! That's why I mentioned it. ;)

Comment: That's honestly a terrible reason to use a plugin for a simple task. It's literally 3 lines of code to create all the table rows you need, and you can even feed that to datatables when you're done. Heck, you can write a jQuery plugin that does this and use it whenever you want. But no, I'm not going to google "JSON to table jquery plugin" for you.

Comment: It's not a loss of time because I use the datatable plugin for many other things inside that site and right because of it I'd like to reuse it.
I asked if there is a way to solve my problem easily than the brute force way cycling the object values and echoing to the dom the tags because I already googled all the net. I did not asked to do it for me!

Comment: You do realize that any plugin you find/write is going to to do "the brute force way cycling the object values and achoing to the dom the tag." You basically want to shrink 3 lines of code to 1 + a plugin. If you just cycled yourself you would probably have your task complete instead of trying to find an "easier" way.

Answer (score 1):

The question wants the results without looping then using '.replace' will help.

```
const obj = {
  "a": "A",
  "b": "B",
  "c": 6
}
let tmp = JSON.stringify(obj,null,1).replace(/[^\w\s]/g,'');
console.log(tmp);
alert(tmp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y1dfLme2/2/

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content: Please give more explanation to your post.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I do not doubt that your answer is incorrect. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer